# How to check the 3d point whether or not visible in threejs?

Tags: three.js

I have use threejs to develop something.
I have a 3d point with the postion just like

```
{
  "x":0.575,
  "y":-1.1366327658835,
  "z":6.35,
}
```

I want to know in my current camera postion, how to check this 3d point whether not visible in my view.

Comment: [Construct view frustum object from camera](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Frustum.setFromMatrix) and then [check if frustum contains point](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Frustum.containsPoint).

Comment: If the point is in your field of view, you probably need a line-of-sight test in order to verify the point is not obscured by other 3D objects. A simple ray intersection test is a good start.

Comment: As others have mentioned, do you want to know if the point is in the view frustum or do you want to know if the point is both in the view frustum AND not blocked by other objects? One way might be to use ["picking techniques"](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-picking.html). Either use a RayCaster, if the position returned is closer than the point your point is blocked. Another is to use GPU picking (same article). Draw a sphere at the point, if that's sphere's id is returned as the result then your point is visible.

Comment: as @mlkn mentioned, frustrum test will solve it. How to construct frustum can be found in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278137/how-to-select-and-highlight-multiple-objects-with-rectangular-selection-ribbon/55285698#55285698