# How to draw a line with the mouse on a 3D surface in threejs

Tags: three.js

I have been looking for an example of how to draw a line with the mouse on a 3D surface within a scene in threejs to achieve the following image but not been able to find an example this specific and was hoping someone could provide an example of how to do this by using the mouse and clicking down to start, dragging, then using mouse up to get the end position. Then using these positions in the 3D space to draw the line.

[image: red line on 3D surface in threejs]

Comment: Valid question, but please specify. Should line be defined by 2D coordinates? Or should it be part of the three.js scene? For example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278137/how-to-select-and-highlight-multiple-objects-with-rectangular-selection-ribbon you will see how to render 2D rectangle on top of three.js canvas.

Comment: The line should be drawn from the mouse down to the mouse up point along the surface of the grid. So the start and end points are on the x and z axis, much like you would drag a piece to a new position on a chess board.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to raycast points to the plane both in mousedown and mousemove, you should do it on mousemove and not in mouseup since the mouse may be released outside of your plane, so keeping track of where the mouse was last during the drag option is the best  approach imo.

```js
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  if (e.button === 0) {
    isMouseDown = true;
    const x = (e.clientX / ctx.renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
    const y = -(e.clientY / ctx.renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
    
    rayCaster.setFromCamera({ x, y }, ctx.camera);
    const intersections = rayCaster.intersectObject(plane);
    if (intersections && intersections.length) {
      hitPoint.copy(intersections[0].point);
      lineGeometry.setFromPoints([ hitPoint, intersections[0].point ]);
      }
  }
});
```

[Sample Pen](https://codepen.io/rogenator/pen/dyvNbzq?editors=0010)